# ¿Como hago para cambiar únicamente el color del texto del botón de SweetAlert2?

Tags: javascript, css, sweetalert2

Para insertar un estilo en un botón de un modal de Sweet Alert, quiero cambiar el color del texto del botón.

```
          Swal.fire({
            confirmButtonColor: '#FFC900',
            title: "Comentario Agregado",
            type: "success"
```

Comprendo que con el `confirmButtonColor`, estableces el color del botón.

¿Como hago para cambiar únicamente el color del texto del botón? ¿que usas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podrías usar la propiedad [`customClass`](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#configuration)

> `customClass` Una clase CSS personalizada para la ventana emergente:
>
> ```
> customClass: {
>   container: '...',
>   popup: '...',
>   header: '...',
>   title: '...',
>   closeButton: '...',
>   icon: '...',
>   image: '...',
>   content: '...',
>   input: '...',
>   inputLabel: '...',
>   validationMessage: '...',
>   actions: '...',
>   confirmButton: '...',
>   denyButton: '...',
>   cancelButton: '...',
>   loader: '...',
>   footer: '....'
> }
> ```

#### Ejemplo:

```js
Swal.fire({
  customClass: {
    confirmButton: 'swalBtnColor'
  },
  title: 'Comentario Agregado',
  icon: 'success'
});
```

```css
.swal2-styled.swal2-confirm.swalBtnColor {
  color: #FFC900
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>
```